# PHP echo prints out end of php tag

Tags: php

So I am trying to use the php echo function to link me to another page on my site. However, it print out my button that I ask for but it also prints out other things such as a period in quotation marks and the semi colon as well as the end php tag.

```
<?php $name = "";echo "<a href='../heroes/" . get_strength_hero($name) . ".html'>" . "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Strength</a></button>";?>
```

This is the PHP code that echos out the button as well as the other elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="full" lang="en">
<!-- Make sure the <html> tag is set to the .full CSS class. Change the background image in the full.css file. -->

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="../includes/functions.php"></script>

    <title>ABADDON</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/hero.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/the-big-picture.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">All</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div id="navbarItems" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <?php $name = "";echo "<a href='../heroes/" . get_strength_hero($name) . ".html'>" . "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Strength</a></button>";?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Agility</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Intelligence</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content --> 
 <h1 id="heroName" class="animated fadeInDown">Abaddon</h1>
              <br>
<h2 id="slogan">              


                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni, iusto, unde, sunt incidunt id sapiente rerum soluta voluptate harum veniam fuga odit ea pariatur vel eaque sint sequi tenetur eligendi.</p>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
<div id="heroportrait">
    <video width="450" height="300" autoplay loop>
        <source src="heroports/abaddon.webm.webm" type="video/webm" />
    </video>
</div>

    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the entire code.

Comment: theres `.` in your syntax.

Comment: Do you get any erros? (error reporting: `<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 ?>`) Also what output do you get?

Comment: @Rafee this `.` is most likely what we call concat :D

Comment: No errors. I can send a pic if needed but here is the output "."Strength"'?> 


(Strength is the button and it does output a button)

Comment: view source, the php is not being parsed at all, is the page *.php? is php installed and working on the server?

Comment: @Lewis check your `anchor` -`</a>` element and `.` where it ends

Comment: what is the code for this function: `get_strength_hero($name)`

Comment: Hey guys, I fixed it. It was pretty silly, but one quotes was missing from the echo line. I am unsure on how it was missing but it is now fixed. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
<a href="../heroes/<a href="../heroes/<?php echo get_strength_hero($name); ?>.html"><button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Strength</button></a>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Strength</button></a>
```

That should work for you.